# Is it possible to create a dynamic field in django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I am creating a project on Django where my apps will work just on Django Admin View (so I dont want to create views or html templates).

I am going to create two App: App One consist on showing just several models for example a Model named Client with client_id, name, country, etc. I can add data to my models, edit, delete, well the typical things you can do on Django Admin.

Then App Two will be a model call Issue. On this model I want to register in database issues related to clients on a country.

So, just with Django Admin I want to click on my model Issue then select a country and when I select the field country (that field will have a Foreign Key Obviously) on another field called country I want several checkbox for all the clientes of that country. The idea is to select with checkbox the clientes of that country that has reported an issue using just Models, Admin and maybe a Forms.py

Thanks in advance

I tried to overwrite admin.py with a personalized forms.py on this way:

```
from django import forms
from Dashboard.models import Country, Client

class Issue (forms.ModelForm):
  
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AsignarForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Obtain country_id
        country_id = self.data.get('country')

        # Then get clients from that country
        if country_id:
            try:
                country = Country.objects.get(pk=country_id)
                client= Client.objects.filter(client=client)
                client_choices = [(client.id, client.name) for client in clients]
            except (ValueError, TypeError, Country.DoesNotExist):
                client_choices = []
        else:
            client_choices = []

        # Define field Client as a ChoiceField with available clients
        self.fields['client'] = forms.ChoiceField(
            choices=client_choices,
            required=False
        )
```